# Combining Rows - Summing Certain Columns and Not Others in R

Tags: r, split-apply-combine

I have a data set that has repeated names in column 1 and then 3 other columns that are numeric.

I want to combine the rows of repeated names into one column and sum 2 of the columns while leaving the other alone. Is there a simple way to do this? I have been trying to figure it out with sapply and lapply and have read a lot of the Q&As here and can't seem to find a solution

```
Name <- c("Jeff", "Hank", "Tom", "Jeff", "Hank", "Jeff",
                       "Jeff", "Bill", "Mark")
data.Point.1 <- c(3,4,3,3,4,3,3,6,2)
data.Point.2 <- c(6,9,2,5,7,4,8,2,9)
data.Point.3 <- c(2,2,8,6,4,3,3,3,1)
data <- data.frame(Name, data.Point.1, data.Point.2, data.Point.3)
```

The data looks like this:

```
  Name data.Point.1 data.Point.2 data.Point.3
1 Jeff            3            6            2
2 Hank            4            9            2
3  Tom            3            2            8
4 Jeff            3            5            6
5 Hank            4            7            4
6 Jeff            3            4            3
7 Jeff            3            8            3
8 Bill            6            2            3
9 Mark            2            9            1
```

I'd like to get it to look like this (summing columns 3 and 4 and leaving column 1 alone. I'd like it to look like this:

```
  Name data.Point.1 data.Point.2 data.Point.3
1 Jeff            3           23           14
2 Hank            4           16            6
3  Tom            3            2            8
8 Bill            6            2            3
9 Mark            2            9            1
```

Any help would great. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Another solution which is a bit more straightforward is by using the library `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)
data <- data %>% group_by(Name, data.Point.1) %>%  # group the columns you want to "leave alone"
  summarize(data.Point.2=sum(data.Point.2), data.Point.3=sum(data.Point.3)) # sum columns 3 and 4
```

if you want to sum over all other columns except those you want to "leave alone" then replace `summarize(data.Point.2=sum(data.Point.2), data.Point.3=sum(data.Point.3))` with `summarise_each(funs(sum))`

Comment: Thanks! I'll try this out. that was an example data set for the question. My true data set has about 50 columns. Is there a way to use the summarize function over a large list of columns? Every time I have used summarize within ddply I had to type out each column and re-name it, as you did.

Comment: I keep getting an error (I have loaded the plyr package): Error: could not find function "%>%"

Comment: its the `dplyr` package

Comment: @akur the data.frame `data` is different from what @user3585829 states it is.

Comment: @dimitris_ps yes, just noticed it now.  Sorry, I didn't check that part before

Comment: Ah. dplyr package. Missed that. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I'd do it this way using `data.table`:

```
setDT(data)[, c(data.Point.1 = data.Point.1[1L], 
                lapply(.SD, sum)), by=Name, 
                .SDcols = -"data.Point.1"]
#    Name data.Point.1 data.Point.2 data.Point.3
# 1: Jeff            3           23           14
# 2: Hank            3           16            6
# 3:  Tom            3            2            8
# 4: Bill            3            2            3
# 5: Mark            3            9            1
```

We group by `Name`, and for each group, get first element of `data.Point.1`, and for the rest of the columns, we compute `sum` by using base function `lapply` and looping it through the columns of `.SD`, which stands for *Subset of Data*. The columns in `.SD` is provided by `.SDcols`, to which we remove `data.Point.1`, so that all the other columns are provided to `.SD`.

Check the [HTML vignettes](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/wiki/Getting-started) for detailed info.

Answer (score 0):

You could try

```
library(data.table)
setDT(data)[, list(data.Point.1=data.Point.1[1L],
    data.Point.2=sum(data.Point.2), data.Point.3=sum(data.Point.3)), by=Name]
#    Name data.Point.1 data.Point.2 data.Point.3
#1: Jeff            3           23           14
#2: Hank            4           16            6
#3:  Tom            3            2            8
#4: Bill            6            2            3
#5: Mark            2            9            1
```

or using `base R`

```
data$Name <- factor(data$Name, levels=unique(data$Name))
res <- do.call(rbind,lapply(split(data, data$Name), function(x) {
                x[3:4] <- colSums(x[3:4])
                x[1,]} ))
```

Or using `dplyr`, you can use `summarise_each` to apply the function that needs to be applied on multiple columns, and `cbind` the output with the 'summarise' output for a single column

```
library(dplyr)
res1 <- data %>%
            group_by(Name) %>% 
            summarise(data.Point.1=data.Point.1[1L])

res2 <- data %>%
            group_by(Name) %>% 
                          summarise_each(funs(sum), 3:4)
cbind(res1, res2[-1])
#   Name data.Point.1 data.Point.2 data.Point.3
#1 Jeff            3           23           14
#2 Hank            4           16            6
#3  Tom            3            2            8
#4 Bill            6            2            3
#5 Mark            2            9            1
```

#### EDIT

The data created and the data showed initially differed in the original post.  After the edit on OP's post (by @dimitris_ps), you can get the expected result by replacing `group_by(Name)` with `group_by(Name, data.Point.1)` in the `res2 <- ..` code.

Comment: Thanks, akrun. The second option worked great. The first option didn't seem to work out well? It gave me different values for Jeff than it should have been. Any ideas? Thanks

Comment: @user3585829  Did you mean the data.table solution is not working as expected?

Comment: @user3585829 I noted that the data you created `data <- data.frame(...)` and the input data showed had some difference in values.  For example, 5th element for 2nd column is 5.

Comment: @user3585829 Anyway, I tried it on both datasets( the one showed, and other created), and the code gives the same expected output.  I am using `data.table_1.9.5` i.e. the devel version